# errors in DSolve a system of ordinary differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, nonlinear

I don't get any answer when I evaluate the following expression:

```
sol = DSolve[{
   x''[t] == -y'[t] x[t], y''[t] == x'[t] x[t]
 , x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, x'[0] == α v Cos[θ]
 , y'[0] == α v Sin[θ]}, {x, y}, t]`
```

I try `NDSolve` as well. But the answer is not correct.

Comment: NDSolve will not work unless you give numerical values for $\alpha$ and $\theta$ and also what is "v" ?

Comment: Do you think it does have a closed-form, symbolic solution?  My interpretation is that `DSolve` doesn't know how to solve it.  In some cases, after some manipulation, it can.  As yet, I don't have an idea what to try.  As a high-order nonlinear system, my outlook is not optimistic.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 1):

**Numerical Solution**

Numerical solution of the ODEs is straightforward.  Suppose, for example, that parameters are chosen such that `α v Cos[θ] == α v Sin[θ] == 1`.

```
sol = Flatten@NDSolve[{x''[t] == -y'[t] x[t], y''[t] == x'[t] x[t], 
    x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0, x'[0] == 1, y'[0] == 1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 5}];
Plot[{x[t] /. sol, y[t] /. sol}, {t, 0, 5}, AxesLabel -> {t, "x, y"}, 
    LabelStyle -> Directive[12, Bold, Black], ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

**Symbolic Solution - Completely Rewritten**

By inspection, `eq2` can be integrated once to obtain

```
eq4 = y'[t] == x[t]^2/2 + α v Sin[θ];
```

Inserting this into `eq1` then gives

```
eq3 = x''[t] + x[t] (x[t]^2/2 + α v Sin[θ]) == 0
```

Solving the latter results in two solutions, the second of which is

```
s = Last@DSolve[eq3, x[t], t] // Simplify
(* {x[t] -> (I JacobiSN[Sqrt[(t + C[2])^2 (v α Sin[θ] + Sqrt[C[1] + v^2 α^2 Sin[θ]^2])]/
   Sqrt[2], (v α Sin[θ] - Sqrt[C[1] + v^2 α^2 Sin[θ]^2])/(v α Sin[θ] + Sqrt[C[1] + v^2 α^2 
   Sin[θ]^2])])/Sqrt[1/(2 v α Sin[θ] - 2 Sqrt[C[1] + v^2 α^2 Sin[θ]^2])]} *)
```

(The other is just its negative.)  Again by inspection `C[2] -> 0` in order that `x[0] == 0`.  To obtain `C[1]`,

```
(Series[s[[1, 2]], {t, 0, 1}] // Normal);
Limit[%, C[2] -> 0];
Flatten@Solve[%/t == α v Cos[θ], C[1]]
(* {C[1] -> 0, C[1] -> v^2 α^2 Cos[θ]^2} *)
```

The first of these yields the trivial solution `x[t] == 0`.  Using the second gives the desired answer.

```
sx = x[t] /. Simplify[Last[s] /. C[2] -> 0 /. Last[%], v α > 0 && t > 0]
(* (I JacobiSN[(t Sqrt[v α (1 + Sin[θ])])/Sqrt[2], 
   (-1 + Sin[θ])/(1 + Sin[θ])])/Sqrt[1/(-2 v α + 2 v α Sin[θ])] *)
```

The corresponding solution for `y[t]` follows immediately, although the result is a bit lengthy to reproduce here.

```
sy = Simplify[y[t] /. Flatten@DSolve[{y'[t] == sx^2/2 + α v Sin[θ], y[0] == 0}, y[t], t]]
```

Plotting the two,

```
Plot[Evaluate@Chop[{sx, sy} /. Sin[θ] -> Sqrt[2]/2 //. v α -> 2/Sqrt[2]], {t, 0, 5}]
```

reproduces the curve above.